# Processing lots of event cancellations and contribution refunds

Tags: civievent, civicontribute

Like probably many of us here, I am faced with cancelling a number of our events and refunding people.  I have probably 10 events to cancel and 200 participants/contributions to deal with.  All event registration payments were made via Stripe.

I just want to be sure I have the optimal workflow.

- Go to Manage Events.
- Pick an event, select participants, registered participants.
- For each person in the list:

  - Click Edit.  This takes me to editing their event registration.
  - Scroll down to the bottom of the window, which shows me their contribution record with a status of Completed.
  - Click Edit on the contribution record.  Now I'm at Edit Contribution.
  - Get the transaction identifier from this window.  Flip over to Stripe Dashboard.  Search for that transaction ID.  Hit refund and accept that customer requested.
  - Go back over to the CiviCRM tab.  Change Contribution Status to Refunded.
  - Click Save.  Now I am back at Edit Event Registration.
  - Change Participant Status to Cancelled.
  - Click Save.  This takes me back to the participant list.

Is this the right workflow?
Is there a faster way?

Thank you